# need help in writing an sql query

Tags: sql

I have this tables in sql
 
**Genre**: genreCode, genreName 
**Movie**: movieCode, movieName, duration, director, publishDate
**Copy**: movieCode , copyNum 
**Belongs**: movieCode, genreCode 
**Language**: languageNum, languageName
**CopiesInLanguages**: movieCode, copyNum, languageNum

how can i get all genres that have movies in all languages in the system? 
thanks for your help :)

Comment: Homework, nice. But if we did it for you, you wouldn't learn much.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need below  -

```
SELECT genreName, COUNT(movieCode)
  FROM Belongs B
  JOIN Genre G ON B.genreCode = G.genreCode
  JOIN CopiesInLanguages CL ON B.movieCode = CL.movieCode
 GROUP BY movieCode
HAVING COUNT(movieCode) = (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(languageNum)
                             FROM Language)
```